# "WindowsError: access violation 000001" on DispatchMessageW in EventLoop

Tags: python, multithreading, winapi, architecture, thread-synchronization

I research Python internals and write GUI Generic windows use Windows API.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import threading
import logging
import uuid

import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

import const


INT = ctypes.wintypes.c_int
LPVOID = ctypes.wintypes.c_void_p
HCURSOR = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
LRESULT = ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM
COLORREF = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD
PVOID = ctypes.wintypes.c_void_p
WCHAR = ctypes.wintypes.c_wchar
BCHAR = ctypes.wintypes.c_wchar
LPRECT = ctypes.wintypes.POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.RECT)
LPPOINT = ctypes.wintypes.POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.POINT)
LPMSG = ctypes.wintypes.POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.MSG)
UINT_PTR = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
LONG_PTR = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE


#WNDPROC = ctypes.wintypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_long, ctypes.wintypes.HWND, ctypes.wintypes.UINT, ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM, ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM)
WNDPROC = ctypes.wintypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)


SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
SW_SHOW = 5

CS_HREDRAW = 2
CS_VREDRAW = 1

CW_USEDEFAULT = 0x80000000

WM_DESTROY = 2


class WNDCLASSEX(ctypes.wintypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.wintypes.UINT),
                ("style", ctypes.wintypes.UINT),
                ("lpfnWndProc", WNDPROC),
                ("cbClsExtra", ctypes.wintypes.INT),
                ("cbWndExtra", ctypes.wintypes.INT),
                ("hInstance", ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("hIcon", ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("hCursor", ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("hBrush", ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("lpszMenuName", ctypes.wintypes.LPCWSTR),
                ("lpszClassName", ctypes.wintypes.LPCWSTR),
                ("hIconSm", ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE)]


class Window(object):
    def __init__(self, app, wclassName=None, wname=u"Custom Title"):
        self.__app = app
        #
        self.__log = logging.getLogger("win_ui.window")
        #
        self.__hInst = app.getInstance()
        self.__hWnd = None
        #
        if wclassName is None:
            wclassName = u"NewWindowClass-{uid}".format(uid=uuid.uuid4().hex)
        #
        self.__wclassName = wclassName
        self.__wname = wname
        #
        #self.__event_dispatcher = EventDispatcher(app=app)
        #self.__event_dispatcher.start()
        #
        self.__has_exit = threading.Condition()
        #
        self._create()

    def wnd_proc(self, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam):
        self.__log.debug("WndProc: hWnd={hWnd!r}, Msg={Msg!r}, wParam={wParam!r}, lParam={lParam!r}".format(hWnd=hWnd, Msg=Msg, wParam=wParam, lParam=lParam))
        #self.__event_dispatcher.push((hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam))
        #
        result = None

        #
        self.__has_exit.acquire()
        self.__has_exit.wait(0.1)
        #
        if Msg == WM_DESTROY:
            self.__app.loadLibrary("user32").PostQuitMessage(0)
            result = 0
        #
        if result is None:
            result = self.__app.loadLibrary("user32").DefWindowProcW(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam)
        #
        self.__has_exit.release()
        #
        return result


    def _create(self):
        WndProc = WNDPROC(self.wnd_proc)

        hBrush = self.__app.loadLibrary("gdi32").GetStockObject(const.LTGRAY_BRUSH)
        print hBrush

        wndClass = WNDCLASSEX()
        wndClass.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)
        wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW
        wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc
        wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0
        wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0
        wndClass.hInstance = self.__hInst
        wndClass.hIcon = 0 #self.__app.loadIcon()
        wndClass.hCursor = 0 #self.__app.loadCursor()
        wndClass.hBrush = hBrush
        wndClass.lpszMenuName = None
        wndClass.lpszClassName = ctypes.c_wchar_p(self.__wclassName)
        wndClass.hIconSm = 0 #self.__app.loadCursor()

        self.__log.debug("wndClass.cbSize = {cbSize!r}".format(cbSize=wndClass.cbSize))
        self.__log.debug("wndClass.lpfnWndProc = {lpfnWndProc!r}".format(lpfnWndProc=wndClass.lpfnWndProc))
        self.__log.debug("wndClass.hInstance = {hInst!r}".format(hInst=wndClass.hInstance))
        self.__log.debug("wndClass.lpszClassName = {lpszClassName!r}".format(lpszClassName=wndClass.lpszClassName))

        result = self.__app.loadLibrary("user32").RegisterClassExW(ctypes.byref(wndClass))
        self.__log.debug("0x0{result:x} = RegisterClassExW(...)".format(result=result))

        #
        self.__x = CW_USEDEFAULT
        self.__y = CW_USEDEFAULT
        self.__width = 300
        self.__height = 300
        #
        exStyle = 0
        #exStyle = const.WS_EX_APPWINDOW
        style = const.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
        #style = const.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | const.WS_CAPTION | const.WS_VISIBLE
        wclassName = ctypes.c_wchar_p(self.__wclassName)
        wname = ctypes.c_wchar_p(self.__wname)
        print wname
        #
        self.__app.loadLibrary("user32").CreateWindowExW.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HWND
        self.__app.loadLibrary("user32").CreateWindowExW.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.wintypes.HWND, ctypes.wintypes.HMENU, ctypes.wintypes.HINSTANCE, ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID]
        #
        self.__hWnd = self.__app.loadLibrary("user32").CreateWindowExW(exStyle, wclassName, wname, style, self.__x, self.__y, self.__width, self.__height, 0, None, self.__hInst, 0)
        self.__log.debug("0x0{hWnd!r} = CreateWindowExW(...)".format(hWnd=self.__hWnd))
        if not self.__hWnd:
            print self.__app.getLastError()
            raise WindowsError("Failed to create window")

        self.__log.debug("ShowWindow(hWnd=0x{hWnd:x})".format(hWnd=self.__hWnd))
        result = self.__app.loadLibrary("user32").ShowWindow(self.__hWnd, SW_SHOW)
        self.__log.debug('0x0{result:x} = ShowWindow(...)'.format(result=result))

        self.__log.debug('UpdateWindow(hWnd=0x{hWnd:x})'.format(hWnd=self.__hWnd))
        result = self.__app.loadLibrary("user32").UpdateWindow(self.__hWnd)
        self.__log.debug('0x0{result:x} = UpdateWindow(...)'.format(result=result))
```

GUI generic window create but cause exception "WidnowsError: access violation 000001" on DispatchMessageW in EventLoop.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import uuid

import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

import const


class Application(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__log = logging.getLogger("win_ui.application")
        self.__libs = {}
        #
        self._event_thread = self.loadLibrary("kernel32").GetCurrentThreadId()

    def loadLibrary(self, name):
        if name in self.__libs:
            result = self.__libs[name]
        else:
            module = getattr(ctypes.windll, name)
            result = self.__libs[name] = module
        return result

    def getInstance(self, hModule=None):
        self.__log.debug('GetModuleHandleW(hModule={hModule!r})'.format(hModule=hModule))
        result = self.loadLibrary("kernel32").GetModuleHandleW(None)
        self.__log.debug('0x0{result:x} = GetModuleHandleW(...)'.format(result=result))
        return result

    def loadIcon(self, iconName=None):
        if iconName is None:
            iconName = const.IDI_APPLICATION
        hInst = self.getInstance()
        result = self.loadLibrary("user32").LoadIconW(hInst, iconName)
        return result

    def loadCursor(self, v=None):
        if v is None:
            v = const.IDI_APPLICATION
        hInst = self.getInstance()
        result = self.loadLibrary("user32").LoadCursorW(hInst, v)
        return result

    def getLastError(self):
        self.__log.debug('GetLastError()')
        result = self.loadLibrary("kernel32").GetLastError()
        #print result
        #rs = self.loadLibrary("kernel32").FormatMessageW(result)
        #print rs
        self.__log.debug('0x0{result:x} = GetLastError()'.format(result=result))
        return result

    def check(self):
        if self._event_thread != self.loadLibrary("kernel32").GetCurrentThreadId():
            raise RuntimeError("Thread?")

    def run(self):
        self.check()

        msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
        lpmsg = ctypes.pointer(msg)

        self.__log.debug('Entering message loop')
        #
        user32 = self.loadLibrary("user32")
        while user32.GetMessageW(lpmsg, 0, 0, 0) != 0:
        #while self.loadLibrary("user32").PeekMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0, const.PM_REMOVE):
            user32.TranslateMessage(lpmsg)
            print lpmsg
            user32.DispatchMessageW(lpmsg)
        #
        self.__log.debug('done.')
```

When I refactoring and calls RegisterWindowEx and CreateWindowEx on separate Python method CreateWindowEx start return 0x0 and GetLastError retrun 0x0. What problem there?

Comment: Don't link to off-site resources. Put the relevant code in your question, ideally as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips on improving your question.

Comment: **UPD** include code into question.

Comment: This is a guess: I wonder if all your debug logging is clobbering `GetLastError()`. Can you try calling it directly (with no logging) immediately after the `CreateWindowEx()` call?

Comment: Yep. I create hook on Windows API calls and have too many working with locks (IntenalLock, EnterCriticalSection, GetTickCount and etc.) between Python method calls. But does not understand why lost registration class between method calls.